# Thinkpad X60 Touchscreen Not Working

Tags: drivers, manjaro, thinkpad, touch-screen, wacom

I'm running Manjaro 32bit on my lenovo x60 tablet, and the touchscreen is working pretty poorly. I've installed the `xf86-input-wacom` package, but whenever I try to click with the digitiser pen, the cursor clicks all over the place, not where my pen was. I found that if I run `sudo systemctl restart wacom-inputattach@ttyS0.service` different devices could appear when I run `xsetwacom list`. So far I have seen the following devices:

```
Wacom Serial Penabled Pen stylus    id: 12  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Serial Penabled Pen eraser    id: 13  type: ERASER  

Serial Wacom Tablet WACf008 stylus  id: 12  type: STYLUS
Serial Wacom Tablet WACf008 eraser  id: 13  type: ERASER
Serial Wacom Tablet WACf008 eraser  id: 14  type: TOUCH

Wacom Serial Penabled 1FG Touchscreen Finger touch  id: 12  type: TOUCH
Wacom Serial Penabled 1FG Touchscreen Pen stylus    id: 13  type: STYLUS
Wacom Serial Penabled 1FG Touchscreen Pen eraser    id: 14  type: ERASER

Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Finger touch  id: 12  type: TOUCH
Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Pen stylus    id: 13  type: STYLUS
Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Pen eraser    id: 14  type: ERASER
```

All of them don't work, except for the second set (Serial Wacom Tablet WACf008 stylus). This is the only one that seems to work reliably, it just doesn't appear very often (in fact, it appears very rarely).

I've also experienced this on Xubuntu before.

If anyone has any workarounds, or fixes to this problem, that would be awesome as I would love to use this laptop with it's touchscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to specify a file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-touchscreen.conf` and remove the `wacom-inputattach@ttyS0.service`.

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-touchscreen.conf
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "Default Layout"
        Screen          "Default Screen"
        InputDevice     "stylus"        "SendCoreEvents"
        InputDevice     "eraser"        "SendCoreEvents"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier      "stylus"
        Driver          "wacom"
        Option          "Device"        "/dev/ttyS0"
        Option          "Type"          "stylus"
        Option          "ForceDevice"   "ISDV4"
        Option          "Mode"          "absolute"
        Option          "SendCoreEvents"        "true"
        Option          "Button2"       "3"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier      "eraser"
        Driver          "wacom"
        Option          "Device"        "/dev/ttyS0"
        Option          "Type"          "eraser"
        Option          "ForceDevice"   "ISDV4"
        Option          "Mode"          "absolute"
        Option          "SendCoreEvents"        "true"
        Option          "Button1"       "2"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier      "intel"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option          "RandRRotation" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Monitor0"
        Device          "intel"
EndSection
```

I didn't know how to disable the Wacom service, so I deleted the service file at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/wacom-inputattach@.service`

With this, the devices I mentioned above didn't show up anymore, and instead the ones specified in the file did. The devices specified in the file work just as well as you'd expect, with no complaints or bugs.

Manjaro Forum thread I started: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/lenovo-x60-tablet-touchscreen-not-working/81887

Answer (score 0):

> [W]henever I try to click with the digitiser pen, the cursor clicks all over the place, not where my pen was.

If "all over the place" happens in reproducible locations – means, the same click location for the same pen location every time – then you might just have to calibrate the touchscreen. The `Serial Wacom Tablet WACf008` device might come with data for pre-calibration somehow, the others might not.

It is a good idea to calibrate a pen input touchscreen anyway, as it increases its accuracy and you can compensate for the apparent position differences that result from different head positions and the non-zero physical depth of the touchscreen device.

To calibrate the touchscreen, you can use `xinput_calibrator` as described in [my other answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/845306).

Comment: I had tried this before, and it didn't work. I had since solved it, however, so I should update this post.